# How to do performance testing of a lambda which is triggered by event bridge?

Tags: aws-lambda, performance-testing, aws-event-bridge, aws-xray

I have a lambda that is triggered whenever an event is dropped in the eventbus to which my lambda is connected and is triggered automatically. How can I performance test it to test how it performs of 500 events are dropped at a time?

Also I know aws has some inbuilt metrics like lambda execution time, xray tracing etc. Can anyone let me know how to use them for my use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "eventbus" you mean [AWS EventBus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_EventBus.html) which is a part of [Amazon EventBrigde](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/index.html) my expectation is that the easiest would be using [PutEvents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutEvents.html) API endpoint, you can come up with a JSON payload having 500 events or make 500 separate calls with 1 event or any combination you can think of.

Be aware that the AWS API requests need to be [signed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) to the load testing tool you choose must have the possibility to calculate this signature. A guide for [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/): [How to Handle Dynamic AWS SigV4 in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aws-sigv4)

With regards to metrics - check out [AWS CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html)